# how to add text inside imagebutton while creating it dynamically

Tags: asp.net

How to add text or label inside image button while creating it dynamically. I have already tried

```
ImageButton imbtn = new ImageButton();
               imbtn.ID = sname;
               imbtn.AlternateText = sname;
imbtn.lable=sname; 
               imbtn.Attributes.Add("src", "./image/" + strText);
               imbtn.AlternateText = sname;
               imbtn.Style.Add("height", "50px");
               imbtn.Style.Add("Width", "90px");
               imbtn.Style.Add("Left", ileft + "px");
               Panel4.Controls.Add(imbtn);
```

this line 4 is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The ImageButton control does not have an attribute 'lable' I guess you want to use ToolTip as a label for your control which is `imbtn.ToolTip = sname`

Having a normal button control with an image

// css class

> ```
> .image-btn-add { 
>         background-image: url("Images/add.png") ;
>         background-repeat: no-repeat;
>         background-position: left;
>         background-size: 20px !important;
>         height: 30px !important;
>     }
> ```

// .aspx file

> ```
>  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="     Add" CssClass="image-btn-add" />
> ```

and here is the dynamic button from the code behind aspx.cs

> ```
>    Button btn = new Button();
>         btn.ID = "Button1";
>         btn.Text = "     Add";
>         btn.CssClass = "image-btn-add";
> ```

and the result will be look like this

[image]

Comment: tooltip works but i have number of button  so to use tootltip to get the name of button is very time consuming.i need such button where i can add both image and text upon it.or the lable below each button

Comment: if you want to have an image and a label for your buttons you can just use normal button control and add image to it. I'll add it on the code above

Comment: i have tried but button doesn't take image may b my code contain problem.can you send me the code plz.

Comment: button i m creating button dynamically.....how to attched this while creating button dynamically

Comment: it's the same as above, I'll add it for you